# Amazon RDS - GUI for DB Parameter Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a some sort of GUI for setting/editing DB Parameter Groups? i.e. Something like [s3fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/amazon-s3-organizers3fox/) for managing Amazon S3 storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://amitech.co/amitech-lab/item/how-to-configurechange-myini-parameters-of-mysql-in-amazon-rds) describes the usage of a tool, Rightscale. It has a free version that should help you.
Hope it helps.